# MySQL session variable won't show

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I have a MySQL session, created using PHP when a user log in to their account. The whole session works and all the regular "text" session objects are displaying properly. However one object, of which I would like to display, is an integer and it seems that is an issue, as it isn't changing. 
The session object is `$conversionsAmount = $_SESSION['conversionAmount'];` which is turned into the variable `echo 'var conversAmount = ' . json_encode(${"conversionsAmount"}) . ';';` and then turned into an int using `echo 'var conversAmountInt = parseInt(conversAmount); ';` and displayed using the following line `echo 'document.getElementById("conversionsAmountID").value = conversAmountInt; ';`
I have also tried to just directly display it, without doing the `parseInt` and that didn't work either.

The issue is also that it doesn't show any errors and nothing in the browser console, which makes it a little difficult, to figure out what is wrong.

I have attached the code below.

```
<?php session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){


  header('location:index.php');
  exit;
  }else{
    $affiLinkWL = $_SESSION['affLinkWL'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $firstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];
    $conversionsAmount = $_SESSION['conversionAmount'];
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

   <h3 id="conversionsAmountID">0</h3>

  </body>

</html>


<?php

  echo '<script>$(document).ready(function() {';

    echo 'var affiLinkWL = ' . json_encode(${"affiLinkWL"}) . ';';
    echo 'var emailAff = ' . json_encode(${"email"}) . ';';
    echo 'var fNameAff = ' . json_encode(${"firstName"}) . ';';
    echo 'var lNameAff = ' . json_encode(${"lastName"}) . ';';
    echo 'var conversAmount = ' . json_encode(${"conversionsAmount"}) . ';';

    echo 'var conversAmountInt = parseInt(conversAmount); ';
    echo 'document.getElementById("linkContainerID").innerHTML = affiLinkWL; ';
    echo 'document.getElementById("emailAffID").innerHTML = emailAff; ';
    echo 'document.getElementById("fNameAffID").innerHTML = fNameAff; ';
    echo 'document.getElementById("lNameAffID").innerHTML = lNameAff; ';
    echo 'document.getElementById("conversionsAmountID").value = conversAmountInt; ';

   echo '});';
   echo '</script>';

?>
```

Comment: Should it possibly be `$conversionsAmount = $_SESSION['conversionsAmount'];` note additional `s` in index to `$_SESSION`? Also, why are you using `${"affiLinkWL"}` instead of `$affiLinkWL`?

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and looking at the HTML source and using `var_dump()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, they are much appreciated. Setting up the error reporting helped, one of the document.getElementById("") statements weren't supposed to be on the page, which meant the last line was never read. Along with that I changed the code a little, to instead of document.getElementById("").value have it be document.getElementById(""). innerHTML and not parseint.